# Trying to install Ubuntu on external hard drive and Grub on internal harddrive - BIOS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, external-hdd, bios

im trying to install ubuntu on my external hard drive and Grub on my internal hard drive, i once installed ubuntu on my internal but i dont have much space on my main SSD, i use a laptop and i decided to replace my old 500gb HDD with a 250gb SSD and i use my old one as an external disk.I already made a question asking how to install this but it was pretty bad an i didnt gave much info.
After i tried to install it and rebooted my computer i got this error:

error: no such device: e5ba289-b231-4ad9-abda-b6a8a04c1c1e
error: unknown file system
entering rescue mode...

After i saw this i rebooted my laptop and booted my USB with ubuntu, and installed boot-repair, after another reboot i got the normal windows 10 starting screen.

I have the log from boot-repair if you need more information please leave a comment and i will give you the required information.

The boot-repair log: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DbS993K8mJ/

Comment: Not a good idea to do what you want Ina BIOS/Legacy installation. Installing Grub in the internal drive works (should work) for booting both OSes but it requires the external drive to be connected regardless of the OS you want to use.

Comment: If your machine is UEFI based then I strongly recommend taking advantage of the UEFI features for dual-boot that hasn't the limitation commented above.

Comment: The Boot-Repair comment on far from start of disk is primarily only for old BIOS systems not using AHCI. But we have seen some with same or similar issue when using USB external drive boot. You may need / (root) inside the first 137GB of drive or a separate /boot partition. You currently have a large NTFS partition at beginning of drive. Windows may not want to read NTFS that is not first, so you have to decide how to partition drive.

Comment: Yeah that NTSF partition is where o store stuff like steam, projects etc. Also I saw that I need to have the disk with Ubuntu always connected for GRUB to work I might just create a 15GB partition for Ubuntu on my internal hard drive and use a 90GB partition on my external hard drive to store what I need, that would be much better tbh since i can just un plug the external hard drive and use it on another computer if I need to